# Jsoup: extract inner tag

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I've this HTML code with a lot of these blocks:

```
    <tr>
     <td headers="header1"><b><a href="www.site.com">TITLE</a></b></td>
     <td headers="header2"><ul class="list_attachments">
     <li><a href="/"><img src='/img/fileicons/pdf.png' alt='pdf'/>A</a>
     </li><li><a href=""><img src='/img/fileicons/pdf.png' alt='pdf'/> B</a>
     </li></ul></td><td headers="header3" class="centrato">DATE</td></tr>
    <tr>
```

In order to iterate in all of these blocks, I tried:

```
Elements elements = document.select("tr").select("td[headers=header1]");
```

This command works, but only select

```
 <td headers="header1"><b><a href="www.site.com">TITLE</a></b></td>
```

instead of all the block. How can I solve this? Isn't possible to say: "jsoup, please select all the  blocks that have an inner ?

Comment: Maybe Elements elements = document.select("tr").select("td") ?

Comment: In this way I have no iterable block...

Comment: Isn't possible to say: "jsoup, please select all the <tr> blocks that have an inner <td headers="header1">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the task of selecting all `<tr>` blocks that contain an inner `<td headers="header1">`, I propose the following solution.

```
Elements elements = document.select("tr:has(td[headers=header1])");
```